# What is the best way for long running background process in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

Recently I was working on a Restaurant Order Management App. So there I had to check for a new order from the server on the background every second. If there is a new order there would be a popup notification. So, I used Alarm Manager with a broadcast receiver and intent service to solve the problem. But the problem is sometimes it is working well and sometimes the service is stopped, it is not working. How can I overcome from this problem? I want a continuous process to run on background even if the app is killed. How can I do this??

I am attaching what I tried so far:

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
class NotificationReceiver:BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object{
        const val TAG = "RECEIVER"
        const val REQUEST_CODE=12345
    }

    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        PreferenceUtils.getInstance().initPreferences(p0!!)
        UtilMethods.printLog(TAG,"Receiver Triggered")

        val i = Intent(p0, OrderNotificationService::class.java)
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            try {
                p0.startForegroundService(i)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            try {

                p0.startService(i)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Intent Service**

```
class OrderNotificationService : IntentService("OrderNotificationService") {

    private var mAudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
    private lateinit var mVibrator: Vibrator

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            try {
                val CHANNEL_ID = "DEMO"
                val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                )

                (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
                    channel
                )

                val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("").build()

                startForeground(10, notification)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    }
     override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {

        myWork()
    }
    }
```

**Registering with alarmManager**

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
        val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NotificationReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        val firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val alarm = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 60*1000, pIntent)
```

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     <service
            android:name=".backgrounds.OrderNotificationService"
            android:exported="false"/>


        <receiver
            android:name=".backgrounds.NotificationReceiver"
            android:exported="true"/>
```

Please Help, Any kind of help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is not to do it at all.  Use push messaging and send a message to the phone when the data on the server has changed, rather than polling constantly.  Your app will work better, and your server won't be deluged with pointless requests.

In general, if you're ever finding yourself polling, you're doing something wrong.  The very few exceptions are when writing very low level device drivers.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your task priority is it deferrable or not. For deferrable task, it's recommended using a workManager with your required constraints. For immediate Task we have various options I recommend Coroutines with channels.